# Something is wrong when I load fxml file in a class constructor

Tags: javafx

I encounter with a problem I can not figure out:

```
public Attribution{
   FXMLLoader loader;
   Group tree;
   Scene scene;
   AttributionNodeController controller; // This is the corresponding controller
   public  Attribution() {
       try {
           System.out.println("Attribution constructor");
           loader = new  FXMLLoader(Attribution.class.getResource("/view/AttributionNode.fxml"));
           tree = loader.load();
           controller = loader.getController();
           scene = new Scene(tree);                    
       } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

}

And, I step debug this program,

```
loader = new FXMLLoader(Attribution.class.getResource("/view/AttributionNode.fxml"));
```

This statement runs pretty well, but then,

```
   tree = loader.load();
   controller = loader.getController();
   scene = new Scene(tree);
```

These three statements will be skiped.

So, why this happens?
Thank you so much for anyone's tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i finally figure it out. In corresponding controller, there are some variables are not correct because I modify the corresponding variable name with JavaFX Builder.